# unable to set security domain via jboss-web.xml

Tags: authentication, configuration, jboss7.x

We have an app that is being deployed as an ear. Within this ear, there is a war that needs to use a specific security domain.

To achieve this, we have configured the standalone-full-ha.xml with the following security section

```
<security-domain name="ourDomain" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="blah.blah.OurDomain" flag="required" />
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

ear/war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml is configured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
   <security-domain>Quark</security-domain>
   <disable-audit>true</disable-audit>
</jboss-web>
```

With this configuration, the app tries to authenticate against the "other" domain which is there in JBoss by default.

log entries as follows:

```
TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-6) PBOX000224: End getAppConfigurationEntry(other), AuthInfo: AppConfigurationEntry[]:
[0]
LoginModule Class: org.jboss.as.security.remoting.RemotingLoginModule
ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: optional
Options:
name=password-stacking, value=useFirstPass
[1]
LoginModule Class: org.jboss.as.security.RealmDirectLoginModule
ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: required
Options:
name=password-stacking, value=useFirstPass
```

When trying to define this as part of the ear in ear/META-INF/jboss-app.xml, that made the whole thing blow up pretty spectacularly - so figured that was less likely to be the way to resolve this.

If the default security domain is changed to `ourDomain` however, it all works as expected.

This doesn't seem to be a big deal - however, it feels better to be able to leave as much of the configuration in the app as possible.

Any pointers to resolve this appreciated.

Comment: What's your server version? I've just checked AS 7.1.1, EAP 6.3.0 and WildFly 8.1.0 and all work fine. The security-domain specified in `ear/war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` is used. (I didn't use any deployment descriptor on EAR level).

Comment: I am on EAP 6.3.0.. It's probably something obvious that's missing but I can't seem to figure it out... :-(

Comment: I have two wars in the ear. Could this be messing it up? The other war does not use a security domain...

Comment: Even this scenario works for me. The app.ear contains app1.war (with `jboss-web.xml` defining my custom security domain `test`) and app2.war (without `jboss-web.xml`). The request to http://localhost:8080/app1/ authenticates against the `test` domain and the request to http://localhost:8080/app2/ authenticates against the `other` (i.e. the default one).

Comment: This is a bit old, the same happens in Jboss 5.1, can you suggest a solution for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Your security domain name specified in `jboss-web.xml` needs to match the name of some security domain in your JBoss config, in your case the web descriptor specifies `Quark` while the security subsystem defined domain named `ourDomain`.

Whenever JBoss can not find the security domain you request in your `jboss-web.xml`, it will fallback to the default security domain, which in case of 7.x is named `other`.